# Jenkins variable has value for CHANGE_AUTHOR populated but not CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm trying to use a Jenkins pipeline which (according to the env-vars.html file) has a number of environment variables available. We have the Git plugin installed so a number of variables are available. Namely some regarding change request builds:

```
CHANGE_AUTHOR
CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME
CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL
```

I can access the variables in my pipeline through the `env` Map and see values set for`CHANGE_AUTHOR` and `CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME` but the value for `CHANGE_AUTHOR_EMAIL` is `null`. It seems it should be populated, accessible since other `CHANGE_AUTHOR*` variables are populated. I'm in the correct build to have it be set. But I don't know where this value is coming from - perhaps there is an additional configuration setting missing which is causing it to be `null`.

Is this a GitHub user profile setting? Is it pulled from the commit? From the PR author details?

I have `user.user` and `user.email` set but I don't know where `CHANGE_AUTHOR_DISPLAY_NAME` comes from and that may help.

Comment: I think this must be related to privacy setting in Github User Profile, In github account *Settings -> Emails -> Keep my email addresses private*, keep it disabled. Also, in *Settings -> Public Profile* select the email id under dropdown '*Public Email*'. This should resolve your issue.